# php and zendguard with asterisk / freepbx

Tags: php5, freepbx

Im running freepbx version 13 and started to upgrade to version 14.
System is on a CentOS 6 system.
The system required certain upgrades first including php which I've upgraded to 5.6.40 and installed zenguardloader 2.6.0
I'm assuming there is some sort of incompatibility between php and zenguardloader as I get the below when I try to run php.

```
[root@bluepukeko ~]# php -a
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: undefined symbol: zend_get_hash_value
Interactive shell

php > echo "Zend engine version: " . zend_version();
Zend engine version: 2.6.0
php > quit
```

The system is also running other active sites so I can't simply wipe the machine and start again, so I need to find an answer to patch the problem.

```
copy ZendGuard.ini

[Zend]
; Enable ZendGuard loader module
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so

; Enables loading encoded scripts. The default value is On
zend_loader.enable=1

; Disable license checks (for performance reasons)
zend_loader.disable_licensing=0

; The Obfuscation level supported by Zend Guard Loader. The levels are detailed in the official Zend Guard Documentation. 0 - no obfuscation is enabled
zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support=0


Copy opcache.ini

; Enable Zend OPcache extension module
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=1

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled for the CLI version of PHP
;opcache.enable_cli=0

; The OPcache shared memory storage size.
opcache.memory_consumption=128

; The amount of memory for interned strings in Mbytes.
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8

; The maximum number of keys (scripts) in the OPcache hash table.
; Only numbers between 200 and 100000 are allowed.
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000

; The maximum percentage of "wasted" memory until a restart is scheduled.
;opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5

; When this directive is enabled, the OPcache appends the current working
; directory to the script key, thus eliminating possible collisions between
; files with the same name (basename). Disabling the directive improves
; performance, but may break existing applications.
;opcache.use_cwd=1

; When disabled, you must reset the OPcache manually or restart the
; webserver for changes to the filesystem to take effect.
;opcache.validate_timestamps=1

; How often (in seconds) to check file timestamps for changes to the shared
; memory storage allocation. ("1" means validate once per second, but only
; once per request. "0" means always validate)
;opcache.revalidate_freq=2

; Enables or disables file search in include_path optimization
;opcache.revalidate_path=0

; If disabled, all PHPDoc comments are dropped from the code to reduce the
; size of the optimized code.
;opcache.save_comments=1

; If disabled, PHPDoc comments are not loaded from SHM, so "Doc Comments"
; may be always stored (save_comments=1), but not loaded by applications
; that don't need them anyway.
;opcache.load_comments=1

; If enabled, a fast shutdown sequence is used for the accelerated code
opcache.fast_shutdown=1

; Allow file existence override (file_exists, etc.) performance feature.
;opcache.enable_file_override=0

; A bitmask, where each bit enables or disables the appropriate OPcache
; passes
;opcache.optimization_level=0xffffffff

;opcache.inherited_hack=1
;opcache.dups_fix=0

; The location of the OPcache blacklist file (wildcards allowed).
; Each OPcache blacklist file is a text file that holds the names of files
; that should not be accelerated.
opcache.blacklist_filename=/etc/php.d/opcache*.blacklist

; Allows exclusion of large files from being cached. By default all files
; are cached.
;opcache.max_file_size=0

; Check the cache checksum each N requests.
; The default value of "0" means that the checks are disabled.
;opcache.consistency_checks=0

; How long to wait (in seconds) for a scheduled restart to begin if the cache
; is not being accessed.
;opcache.force_restart_timeout=180

; OPcache error_log file name. Empty string assumes "stderr".
;opcache.error_log=

; All OPcache errors go to the Web server log.
; By default, only fatal errors (level 0) or errors (level 1) are logged.
; You can also enable warnings (level 2), info messages (level 3) or
; debug messages (level 4).
;opcache.log_verbosity_level=1

; Preferred Shared Memory back-end. Leave empty and let the system decide.
;opcache.preferred_memory_model=

; Protect the shared memory from unexpected writing during script execution.
; Useful for internal debugging only.
;opcache.protect_memory=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Piotr
After much swearing and cursing I basically concluded that I was just wasting my time. While I could get Asterisk and FreePBX operating with a other functions running on the machine, when I tried to do any update the system slowly just screwed itself and the effort of cleaning up the mess just wasn't worth the heart ache.
I eventually threw in the towel and now have a dedicated machine running virtulisation giving me 10 virtual machine and all are playing happily together.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  You can indicate that the problem has been "solved" by clicking the checkmark to accept the answer.